# unable to connect local server using Apache http in android?

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

installed XAMPP server, created database and successfully accessed it from chrome  However whenever i try to run application from my ASus device, its refusing to connect my IP address.

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
  http://192.XXX.X.XXX refused
how can i solve this issues??

Comment: first use the same subnetwork(obviously, it will not work if your device using 3g)  or make it visible via routing, then is still not working, dissable the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Instead of http://192.xxx.x.xxx/ try to use localhost. If your Apache runs on XAMPP. And make sure you have permissions in Manifest ACCESS_NETWORKSTATE

Comment: Using localhost is nonsense as XAMPP is not running on the Asus. And that permission is nonsense too.

Comment: I understand but i am gettting this issue before its working but dont know what happen it stop working ans actually i have saw all the issue but could not figure out till now..!! Anybody helps???